# Material skin gone when i use ismdicontainer

Tags: c#

I have one form with IsMdiContainer = True and when I run the form material skin disappears.

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92z9H.png)

below is when I run the form material skin just disappear.

[Material Skin Gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PJfD.png)

Form Code

```
 MaterialSkinManager materialSkinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
        materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
        materialSkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.LIGHT;

        // Configure color schema
        materialSkinManager.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(
            Primary.Blue400, Primary.Blue500,
            Primary.Blue500, Accent.LightBlue200,
            TextShade.WHITE
        );
```

in the form i have ShowForm

```
 private void ShowForm(Form f)
    {
        f.MdiParent = this;
        f.Show();
        f.Activate();
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: sorry for that.